# Extract specific or multiple word in cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a problem in excel.

I want just

SCV110FIDR357--------------------->  SCV110F ID

SCV110FF5IDR321X-------------------> SCV110FF 5ID

SCV110F5IDR321X-------------------------> SCV110F 5ID

Comment: Use VBA.Get started on something and come back to edit your question and show your effort if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If your examples are in A1,A2 and A3 then in B1 type:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("ID",A1)+IF(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("ID",A1)-1,1)),-1)<0,-1,-2))&" "&MID(A1,SEARCH("ID",A1)+IF(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("ID",A1)-1,1)),-1)<0,0,-1),+IF(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("ID",A1)-1,1)),-1)<0,2,3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Jeeped.  You answered while I was still typing :p  ![Results](http://fivebs.net/fiddle/jeeped.PNG)

Comment: fwiw, I've found that it is best to add a short note stating something like **The [NUMBERVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NUMBERVALUE-function-1B05C8CF-2BFA-4437-AF70-596C7EA7D879) was introduced with Excel 2013. It is not available in earlier versions.** The OP did specify [excel-2007] after all.

Comment: I missed that it was [excel-2007] :o

Answer (score 0):

For your limited sample data, this formula might do.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2, FIND("ID", A2)-1, 1)), LEFT(A2, FIND("ID", A2)-2)&" "&MID(A2, FIND("ID", A2)-1, 1)&"ID", LEFT(A2, FIND("ID", A2)-1)&" ID")
```

Beyond adding an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to cover data that doesn't follow the pattern you've provided, anything more complex should probably be done with a VBA **UDF** but more sample data together with expected results would be necessary before attempting the code.

[image: limited samples]

Comment: thank you sir, it is working properly